# Moving contacts

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel

How do I move a large contact list on my pc to my new Mac address book?  I moved the excel file to my iMac, but have trouble moving the info to my address book.

Answer (score 1):

First, open the Excel document and re-save it as a CSV (Comma Separated Values) file. Copy the new file to your Mac. Open up Address book and go to File -> Import. Select the CSV file and import it. Barring any formatting issues, the contacts should get transferred over without a problem.